# Bootstrap affix does not work when navigating back

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used Bootstrap affix to create a fixed position div that behaves similar to the "How to Format" and "Similar Questions" div that appears when you ask a new question in Stackoverflow. It works fine when I load the page the first time, but if I scroll quite far down the page, navigate away, and then return to the page with the back button, the affixed div will sometimes be affixed in the wrong place, and sometimes the fixed positioning will break and it will simply return to its normal place in the document.

Is there something wrong with how I am implementing affix?

Document layout (`#engage` is the affixed div). It should not scroll over `#title` or `#footer`:

[image]

**Javascript**

```js
$('#engage').affix({
    offset: {
        top: $('#donation-content').offset().top,
        bottom: function () {
            return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true))
        }
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```css
#engage.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

@media(max-width:767px){

   #engage.affix {
    position: static;
    }
}
```

You can find example code at http://www.bootply.com/pxyz1hsefA. Errors tend to happen if you scroll to the bottom of the page, click on "Go somewhere else", then click on the back button. Violent scrolling up and down will also tend to break it.

**Edit:**
Adding an `.affix-bottom` class to the css with absolute positioning goes some way to fixing it. At least now when it's 'broken' the div just sticks to the bottom of its scrolling range. When I scroll back to the top, it resumes it's correct fixed position again. But it's still not what I'd call stable.

```css
#engage.affix-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  }
```

Comment: Is this browser/platform specific? Just tried quickly Chrome and Firefox on OSX and I can't see the described problem…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem I was experiencing was due to a mismatch between the top and bottom offset values, leading to the affix plugin not knowing what state it should be in. It may be a bug in the affix plugin or how it is applied (read more at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4647). It also seems to manifest differently in different browsers.

In my case I could only solve it by removing the bottom offset:

```
$('#engage').affix({
    offset: {
        top: $('#donation-content').offset().top
        }
});
```

This does mean that the fixed div can overlap the footer in some situations, which is not ideal but it is more stable. I am marking this as the accepted answer for now, because it does solve the problem, though it does leave unfortunate side-effects.

Comment: Appology for the lateness, just a minor sidenote; though this solved my problem, an extra closing brace appears in the code. Just thought it would be a good heads up for future reference. +1

Comment: Thanks @DaveWoodhall, I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a tiny timeout fixed my issue. Removing one of the offset settings (top or bottom) helps too but wasn't an option for me.